# How can I set my DatePicker dialogue in my application

Tags: android

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm:ss, context. GetResources().getConfiguration().locale); 

simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
return simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(myDate));
```

This code only showing me date when I save my note, it doesn't allow me to pick a date for my event

Comment: Where is datepicker dialog code?

Comment: Check this : https://gist.github.com/pratikbutani/036e73e26139096e3b0ba91f85e23d85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display Datepicker Dialog using below way

```
// Global declaration
Calendar preferDate1 = new GregorianCalendar();
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
private int year, month, day;
```

Set Below code in OnClick method

```
DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, preferredDate1Picker, preferDate1.get(Calendar.YEAR), preferDate1.get(Calendar.MONTH), preferDate1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
dp.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());//Only if You want to set min date
dp.show();
```

And Add this in MainClass

```
private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener preferredDate1Picker = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        preferDate1 = new GregorianCalendar(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay);

        textview.setText((selectedDay < 10 ? "0" + String.valueOf(selectedDay) : String.valueOf(selectedDay)) + "/"
            + (selectedMonth + 1 < 10 ? "0" + String.valueOf((selectedMonth + 1)) : String.valueOf((selectedMonth + 1)))
            + "/" + selectedYear);

    }
};
```